# Changing TFS Admin Account Password

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been asked to change the password of our TFS Admin account.  This is NOT one of the accounts that runs any of the services.  This is the account that has admin level privelages in TFS and can do anything in TFS.

Is there anything I should be aware of when doing this?  Are there any negative side effects or concerns to watch out for?

Answer (score 2):

No, there should not be any issues if this is not a service account.